# Tableau - Custom SQL query to retrieve data from Mongodb

Tags: sql, mongodb, datetime, tableau-api, date-range

Below query is executed through Tableau Custom SQL after connecting to Mongodb.
Seems like the date field function in WHERE statement gives an error message.

This is the error message:

> [Simba][MongoDBODBC] (110) Error from MongoDB Client: Failed to read 4
>   bytes from socket within 300000 milliseconds. (Error Code: 4)

I want to pull data based for the field below for last 3 months.

```
SELECT 
"orders_transitions"."CHILD" AS "CHILD",
"orders_transitions"."PARENT" AS "PARENT",
"orders_transitions"."Start_Time" AS "Start_Time",
"orders_transitions"."Order_Date" AS "Order_Date",
COUNT("orders_transitions"."ORDER_ID") AS "cnt_ORDER_ID_ok"

FROM "orders_transitions"

WHERE "orders_transitions"."Order_Date" > CAST('4/01/2016 11:00:00 AM') AS Date

GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of the error, but your `CAST` syntax looks incorrect. Should probably be: `CAST('4/01/2016 11:00:00 AM' AS DATE)`

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you connecting to, and which version of the MongoDB driver?